# iPhone alarm volume so high

Tags: iphone

Every time I set an alarm on my iPhone 11 (iOS 14.4) the volume is so annoyingly high. I've tried to lower it from the side buttons but the alarm's volume seems not to be affected. I've also tried to lower it from `Settings` > `Sound & Haptics` > `Ringer and Alerts` but the volume blasts my eardrums nonetheless every time I set an alarm. I'd really love some help in lowering it if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone 4S Alarm Volume](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50713/iphone-4s-alarm-volume)

Comment: Not really, it doesn't explain how I can prevent the volume from blasting every time I set an alarm.

Comment: Turn down the ringer volume. Depending on your iPhones settings you can do that with the volume keys (you'll notice wether the bar is on the side or on top reading "Ringer") or you'll have to go to settings and open "Sounds & Haptics"

Comment: Yes I've tried both those things (just updated my question with details). Unfortunately, it makes no difference.

Comment: Using an audio editor (like Audition), import your ringtone (or choose a song you like) and reduce the volume there. Then save it and import it into Music and sync it onto your iPhone. Finally set that track as the default ringtone.

Comment: If that doesn't work: iOS may be normalizing the volume. If so, you have to merge many songs or the same song repeated together (at least ~30 min total so the volume is kept low until the alarm stops itself), reduce the volume, and apply a gradual volume increase for the last 1 or 2 minute. Same procedure afterwards.

Comment: If that still doesn't work (i.e. iOS is using a limiter / dynamic range compression automatically based on average volume): just give up. Or try upgrading your system, and then erasing your iPhone and start again.